# Quantum Calculus Prove Q Binomial Coefficient Analogue

Tags: combinatorics, gaussian, quantum-calculus

[image]

Parts a and b are trivial so those are of no concern. My conclusion for part c is that a proper q analog is the q binomial coefficient, counting the number of subspaces of dimension k in a vector space of dimension n whereas dimension n is over a finite field of q elements. However, this just seems like something "that is" and not something I can think of how to prove..

Comment: Use the q-Pochhammer and then it’s regular pochhammer symbol gamma function definition to find the q gamma function [like this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html). Also this looks like a problem statement question, so please [add more detail](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you very much for the response. I am not familiar with the  q-Pochhammer. What would I apply it to?

Comment: You can derive many other “q functions” from it and it is useful for many products/sums: [Q-Pochhammer Symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html)

Comment: @TymaGaidash Awesome. So I am to take the original function and apply the  q-Pochhammer? I am very lost...

Comment: I may have explained it a bit weirdly, so please just see [equation (1) and (3) in this article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html).

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be an $\mathbb F_q$-vector space with dimension $n$.

$\binom{n}{m}_q\binom{m}k_q$ enumerates pairs of subspaces $(M,K)$ so that $K\subseteq M\subseteq N$, $\dim M=m$ and $\dim K=k$.

On the other hand, in order to choose $(M,K)$, you could first choose $K$ in $\binom{n}k_q$ ways, and then count the number of ways to choose $M$ for that given $K$. Subspaces of $N$ containing $K$ are in bijection with subspaces of $N/K$ (fourth isomorphism theorem). Therefore, the number of subspaces of $N$ containing $K$ with dimension $m$ is equal to the number of subspaces of $N/K$ with dimension $m-k$, or $\binom{n-k}{m-k}_q$.

Putting this altogether, we see that the original identity still holds when you stick little $q$-subscripts on all of the binomial coefficients.